# How to pass javascript variable in class?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code for quiz,whenever one option is selected by the user from out of four option,i want to alert. I have something similar to my code here:-

```
<label class="alert optiona">
</lablel>
```

I am having value

```
data.correct="optiona";
```

I need to send pass the value in javascript.When i am passing following syntax , it doesnt send the value of data.correct.

```
$(".alert "+data.correct).attr("class", "alert alert-"+ data.mode);
```

Comment: You probably want `</label>` and not `</lablel>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the dot in the selector and you have a space which means that the second class applies to a descendant of the `.alert` element.

Change

```
$(".alert "+data.correct)
```

to

```
$(".alert."+data.correct)
```